# Node.js: Callback function at the end of each iteration in a for loop

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

In Node.js I have a function that goes through an entire list of elements and does some database calls as shown below:

```
 for(var j=0; j<elements.length; j++)
 {
   //do some database calls
 }
```

After each loop finishes (meaning when the database calls terminate), I would like to "console.log("Loop terminated");". In the code below I have shown my attempt to solve this:

```
 for(var j=0; j<elements.length; j++)
 {
   (function() 
     {
      //do some database calls

     })(function(){
        console.log("Loop terminated");
       });
 }
```

I use an anonymous function in place, and I am trying to callback a function that will print "console.log("Loop terminated")". When I execute this code, the console.log never prints anything. I am pretty new to Node.js and I do not understand callbacks that well. Can someone explain to me why my callback is not working and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you intend to make database calls in parallel:

```
 numCompletedCalls = 0
 for(var j=0; j<elements.length; j++)
 {
    callDatabase(function(results) {
       numCompletedCalls++;
       if (numCompletedCalls == elements.length)
          console.log("Done all calls!");

    });
 }
```

if you are going to save all results you can push to `allResults` array and check it's length instead of incrementing counter.

If you want to have sequential for loop, you need to have recursion-like pattern (note that it's not actually recursion)

```
 function iterateElements(elements, index, callback) 
 {
    if (index == elements.length)
       return callback();
    // do database call with element
    var ele = elements[index];
    callDatabase(function(results) {
       iterateElements(elements, index+1, callback);
    });
 }
 iterateElements(elements, 0, function() {
    console.log("Done all calls!");
 });
```

most people tend to use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library, but I strongly recommend to try all async patterns manually at least once